# What is the origin of the phrase "beyond the pale"?

Tags: expressions

What's the origin of the phrase 'beyond the pale'?

Comment: If you are not aware of this: "Beyond the Pale" literally refers to a specific part of Eireland (as seen by the English colonialists).  Tim explains why the English used that phrase: Reg explains the roots.  (It's reminiscent of the phrase in Australia, "back of Burke.")

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beyond_the_pale

Answer (score 16):

From [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-pal2.htm):

> *Pale* is an old name for a pointed piece of wood driven into the ground and — by an obvious extension — to a barrier made of such stakes, a palisade or fence. *Pole* is from the same source, as are *impale*, *paling* and *palisade*. This meaning has been around in English since the fourteenth century and by the end of that century *pale* had taken on various figurative senses — a defence, a safeguard, a barrier, an enclosure, or a limit beyond which it was not permissible to go. The idea of an enclosed area still exists in some English dialects.
>   [...]
>   The earliest figurative sense that’s linked to the idiom was of a sphere of activity or interest, a branch of study or a body of knowledge, which comes from the same idea of an enclosed or contained area; we use *field* in much the same way. This turned up first in 1483 in one of the earliest printed books in English, *The Golden Legende*, a translation by William Caxton of a French work.

The Phrase Finder [adds](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/beyond-the-pale.html) that the first printed reference of the phrase "beyond the pale" (rather than just the word *pale* in its figurative sense) comes "from 1657 in John Harington's lyric poem *The History of Polindor and Flostella*."

> In that work, the character Ortheris withdraws with his beloved to a country lodge for 'quiet, calm and ease', but later venture further - 'Both Dove-like roved forth beyond the pale to planted Myrtle-walk'. Such recklessness rarely meets with a good end in 17th century verse and before long they are attacked by armed men with 'many a dire killing thrust'. The message is clearly, 'if there is a pale, you should stay inside it', which conveys exactly the meaning of the phrase as it is used today.

Comment: How interesting that the second quote is basically reflecting the plot of most modern horror movies. The more things change...

Comment: * savage Irish = my relatives.

Comment: I found an earlier printed reference of the phrase from 1628 [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=ucGRAAAAMAAJ&q=%22beyond+the+pale%22&dq=%22beyond+the+pale%22&hl=en&ei=_aSGTczSKKaX0QGB0ZnZCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBDgo).

Answer (score 14):

When the Normans invaded Ireland in the twelfth century, they were not as successful as they hoped: the English possessions were gradually reduced to an area round Dublin.  This was originally protected by a palisade (or Pale), and (in English eyes at least) Ireland was divided unto the civilised part within the Pale and the barbarian part "Beyond the Pale", which became a common phrase for the Elizabethans, if not earlier.

Answer (score 6):

*Pale* in this idiom comes from Latin *pālus* 'stake'; it means a fencepost, and by ordinary extension it also means the fence itselt, and the area it contains or delimits.

So *beyond the pale* just means "outside the boundaries". Normally, of course, the "boundaries" are metaphors for human activities, rather than referring to a physically bounded location.

Comment: In the late Middle Ages that part of Ireland under English control was known as the Pale, so 'beyond the Pale' was a term used to refer to being outside or beyond the area of English control, ie uncivilised.

Comment: Right, whence the modern sense of "over the top; not done; bad form", all of which correlate with "foreign, and therefore uncivilized". It was also used for Jewish ghettos.

Comment: It is far more likely that 'Pale' refers to the the old English word for region or settlement region. Source: Oxford Dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

[Etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pale&allowed_in_frame=0) says of **pale (n.)**:

> early 14c., "fence of pointed stakes," from L. *palus* "stake," related to *pangere* "to fix or fasten" (see *pact*). Figurative sense of "limit, boundary, restriction" is from c.1400. Barely surviving in *beyond the pale* and similar phrases. Meaning "the part of
>   Ireland under English rule" is from
>   1540s.

Comment: But surviving in its derivative *paling*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - although in that sense it's meaning has changed to 'say stupid things in a political campaing'

Answer (score 0):

I have always heard that it refers to the [Pale of Settlement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_of_settlement), but that name likewise came from pale meaning "stick".

Comment: It probably had similar meanings in different parts of the world.