# Word or phrase for remoteness, great distance from human habitat

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase denoting remoteness and great distance from human habitat, for the purpose of naming a cabin in the wilderness. I have already thought of "far cry" and "back of beyond". It would be good if the word or phrase was associated with a quotation or title from a book or proverb, but mostly it needs to resonate with the idea of a place "far from the madding crowd".

Comment: _Antipodes_. For a benefit, it's pronounced rather strangely, because it's Greek: /æn'tɪpədiz/

Comment: Hmmm, _antipodes_ just means 'opposite the feet' i.e. on the other side of the world. Doesn't necessarily convey remoteness.

Answer (score 3):

**[Timbuktu](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_does_as_far_as_timbuktu_mean)** - a place that is unimaginably far away, completely foreign, or unreachable.

Even though Timbuktu is a real city in central Mali, it was (and still is) a term used to describe a far away place. It doesn't carry the meaning of a place far from human habitat, though. But it is certainly meant to imply a place far from major human habitat.

**[Outback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outback#Terminology)** - remote area, especially in Australia: a sparsely inhabited or wilderness region of a country, especially of Australia; The remote and usually uninhabited inland regions of Australia.

There is an interesting discussion at the link about the origin of the term *outback*, including terms like **Never-Never** (meaning the remoter parts of the outback), **Black Stump**, **Beyond the Black Stump** (and there are Black Stump Run and Black Stump Creek). Also **Back of Beyond**, as you mentioned.

You might consider **[Never Never Land](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/never-never-land.html)**, which is closely related to *Never-Never*.

Then there is the much less polite **Bumf$%k, Egypt**, which is [described](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bumfuck%20egypt) as someplace hard to get to and generally undesirable; the **boonies** or **toolies**. **[The middle of nowhere](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bumfuck,_Egypt)**. It's where soldiers get sent when they are deployed, hence the scornful language.

**[Beyond the pale](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6305/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-beyond-the-pale)** was covered very well in the linked ELU thread. Requoting from that thread:

> The message is clearly, 'if there is a pale, you should stay inside it', which conveys exactly the meaning of the phrase as it is used today.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned *isolated* yet. The cabin could be named "The [Isolation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/isolation)" (or possibly "The Isolator", if occupants are sent there as punishment).

**isolated**, adjective –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=isolated%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

> far away from other places, buildings, or people; remote.

Comment: I think issuing monikers at SE is either off-topic or at least, generally frowned upon. *This* is the WORD for, "remoteness, great distance from human habitat."

Comment: OK, guess I got a little carried away. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound harsh, my comment was more to everyone else. Yours at least takes a correct word and makes it a name. Some of the others provided *names* of imaginary places that are typically isolated.

Answer (score 2):

How about one of the following:

- backwoods
- boondocks
- in the sticks
- terra incognita
- hinterland
- bush
- out-of-the-way
- removed

I hope that at least one of these has the shade of meaning you're looking for

Comment: Did you know that "boondocks" comes from "bundok", the Tagolog (native Phillipine) word for mountain?

Answer (score 2):

How about [(ultima) Thule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultima_Thule), a mediaeval term used to denote “any distant place located beyond the ‘borders of the known world’”?

It’s a town and former municipality in the north of Greenland as well, named for its remoteness.

Or perhaps, if you’re fond of comics, *Faroffistan* (from a 1958 Dumbo strip by Carl Fallberg and Paul Murry). In the Scandinavian translations of this strip, the word *Langtbortistan* (Danish)/*Långtbortistan* (Swedish) was coined, and this term has since become a common word in both languages to describe a more or less fictional, remote place.

Answer (score 1):

***lost***

> Beyond reach, communication, or influence: *lost river*
>
> [AHDEL](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Lost&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)

***backwater***

> An isolated or backward place or condition.
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/backwater)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exactly evoke vacation, but **desolation** might work. The [Kerguelen Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerguelen_Islands) are one of the most remote places on the planet and are also known as the Desolation Islands.

Another word that comes to mind is **secluded**, which is not just remote but also somewhat hidden.

Answer (score -1):

For the context you've given, I'd use **an isolated getaway**.

Comment: Not my down vote. I think this is already part of another answer.